# How do I find the maximum depth of a tree?

Tags: python, tree

I have a tree data structure, defined as below:

```
class Tree(object):
    def __init__(self, name='ROOT', children=None):
        self.name = name
        self.children = []
        if children is not None:
            for child in children:
                self.add_child(child)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
    def add_child(self, node):
        assert isinstance(node, Tree)
        self.children.append(node)
```

I need to write a function to find the depth of the tree.  Here is the function I wrote (takes a Tree as input, and returns an integer value as output), but it is not giving the right answer:

```
def depth(tree): 
    count = 1
    if len(tree.children) > 0:
        for child in tree.children:
            count = count + 1
            depth(child)
    return count
```

How do I correct it?

Comment: What happens to the return result when you call `depth(child)`?

Comment: How high past 1 does `count` count?

Comment: The depth function is not correct as a recursive function.
You have to set count as argument like def depth(tree, count=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your `depth(child)` does do the recursive call, it does *not* do anything with the return value (the depth). You seem to be simply counting the nodes at a given level and calling that the depth (it's really the width).

What you need is something like (pseudo-code):

```
def maxDepth(node):
    # No children means depth zero below.

    if len(node.children) == 0:
        return 0

    # Otherwise get deepest child recursively.

    deepestChild = 0
    for each child in node.children:
        childDepth = maxDepth(child)
        if childDepth > deepestChild:
            deepestChild = childDepth

   # Depth of this node is one plus the deepest child.

   return 1 + deepestChild
```

Answer (score 2):

How about you just do a max of all the depth on each node recursively?

```py
def max_depth(self, depth=0):
    if not self.children:
        return depth
    return max(child.max_depth(depth + 1) for child in self.children)
```